# mysql procedure/ function

Tags: mysql, optimization

I'm trying to develop a voting application which requires advanced database queries. The application allows users to vote other users using their telephone numbers. So make sure a user with many phone numbers get all their votes tallied together, I have a table associating their phone numbers using their national ID number. In the end I have two tables as so:

user_national_id table

user_phone_no | national_id 
-------------------- | -----------------
phone1              | nat_id1
phone2              | nat_id1

votes table

user_phone_no | sender 
-------------------- | -----------------
phone1              | sender1
phone1              | sender2
phone2              | sender3
phone2              | sender2

I now need a method which collects unique national ID numbers in user_national_id table, associate the national ID to user phone  numbers in user_national_id table then count the number of times the returned phone numbers occur in the votes table.

Thanks in advance.

(moved from comment...)

```
DELIMITER $$ 
    CREATE  PROCEDURE GetUniqueNominees()
    BEGIN DECLARE done BOOLEAN;
    DECLARE nomIds VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE curIds CURSOR FOR 
      SELECT  DISTINCT national_id
          FROM  user_national_id;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=TRUE;
    OPEN curIds;
    LOOPROWS: LOOP
      IF done=TRUE THEN
        CLOSE curIds;
        LEAVE LOOPROWS;
      END IF;
      FETCH curIds
        INTO  nomIds;
      SELECT  DISTINCT nomIds;
      select  count(user_phone_no)
        from  votes
        inner join  user_national_id
          ON (votes.user_phone_no = user_national_id.user_phone_no)
        where  national_id=nomIds;
    END LOOP;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: @mmushtaq I am not good in Sql but i tried joins which clearly did not work

Comment: this is what I have come up with so far

Comment: the problem is that it returns each result twice

Comment: Which tables is `national_id` in?  (missing qualification in query.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL does not usually need loops and cursors, and often (though not always), when you think you need them, you don't.

SQL is not intended to be procedural, it is intended to be declarative:  you tell the server what you want -- not how the server should get it.  The server (the query optimizer) is then free to implement whatever logic it can think of to calculate the result, as long as it's logically consistent with what you are asking.

In this case, here's the way to express what you seem to be asking:

```
SELECT u1.national_id, COUNT(DISTINCT v.sender) AS votes_counted
  FROM user_national_id u1
  JOIN user_national_id u2 ON u2.national_id = u1.national_id
  JOIN votes v ON v.user_phone_no = u2.user_phone_no
 WHERE u1.user_phone_no = ?
 GROUP BY u1.national_id
```

Here, we use two "virtual copies" of the user_national_id table, aliased as u1 and u2.  We find the entered phone number in u1, which gives is the user's national id.  From that, we find the same national id in u2, which gives us *all* of the user's phone numbers, and from there, we count the votes (by counting the senders) for all phone numbers matching the phone numbers we found in u2, based on the criteria from u1.  We count the `DISTINCT` sender, which discards duplicate votes, since the current structure seems to allow me to vote for a user's different phone numbers but I assume those shold be ignored.  If not, remove `DISTINCT`.

`DISTINCT` is another feature typically abused by SQL neophytes, which often is a sign that "my query is wrong but for some reason this seems to fix it."  Don't use it casually, carelessly, or routinely, and don't use it without a specific justification.  Here, the justification seems apparent.

Comment: **AWESOME STUFF! WORKS LIKE A CHARM**

Answer (score 0):

hum if i understood it well it should be :

```
select count(sender) from votes inner join user_national on (votes.user_phone_no = user_national.user_phone_no) where national_id = {yourValueHere}
```

Comment: That really works when you already know the national ID number.

Comment: My problem i to fetch distinct national Id loop through the result and count as you have done. So that the national ID will be supplied dynamically.